# What the "16 MB of data limit" actually is of the `BatchWriteItem` API in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

According to the doc:

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.

The definition is unclear, `16 MB of data` of what..?

1. The whole HTTP request(header+body)?
2. The total size of [RequestItems.*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#DDB-BatchWriteItem-request-RequestItems) ?
3. If 2 is true, is the size of **marshall** or **unmarshall** data? (Same question applies to `Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB` too)

Does anyone know the details for this? I wasn't able to find any information on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The individual item size limit of `400KB` applies to the serialized item, in DynamoDB format, which looks something like:

```
{
  "attr1": { "S": "foo" },
  "attr2": { "N": "100" },
  ...
}
```

Since `25 x 400KB` is `10000KB` which is just under `10MB`, then it follows that the limit of `16MB` must apply to either the whole request payload, or the whole request payload + headers. The bulk of the overhead comes from the serialization of the request wrappers (ie. the serialization of the actual PutItem, UpdateItem, or DeleteItem request metadata)

I can't imagine headers getting so big as to make a significant difference out of 16MB, so you can pretty much focus on the body for that limit.

I think the sensible thing to do is to take the size of the serialized request body and make sure it doesn't get too close to 16MB.

I was going to say you could try it yourself but since you'll much sooner run into the `25 items x 400KB/ item` limit I don't think there's a very easy way to prove this is right. But then again, it sort of means that the `16MB` limit shouldn't be the biggest concern..

Comment: When you said "`10000KB` which is just under 10MB", I think you were thinking in KiB and MiB instead of KB and MB.

Comment: heh -- I had to google KiB vs KB to figure out what you meant -- pretty much everybody I know uses "KB" to mean 1024 Bytes and "MB" to mean "1024 KB == 1024*1024 Bytes"; in the end those +/-24 bytes are not super important to the construction of the argument (found this when I searched for KiB vs KB: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/files-size-units-kib-vs-kb-vs-kb#:~:text=%221%20KB%22%20means%201024%20bytes,unambiguous%2C%20but%20perhaps%20unfamiliar%20terminology)

Comment: Thanks Mike Dinescu !!  it sounds reasonable, but I think I have to ask the AWS tech support  for the "right" answer..! I'll post their answer later on after I got there response.